Use LinkedIn API to obtain the talents' profile info?
When we search LinkedIn Web Page, we can find following info for a given talented person.

Name: John Doe
Summary: CEO, CTO, and Perl mongers in the Example.com
Location: Example city, United States, texas
Experience: Worked as xxx chemistry product manager in 1980. in 1980 founded example.com...etc...
Eduucation: 1970 Example univ. PH.D. (Chemistry), 1975 Example univ. Master (Computer Science)...etc...

I heard LinkedIn provides us API.
So my question is, can we obtain (extract) the information as dotted line above with the API?
I want to create the system:

Input: URL of each person
Output: Name, Summary, Location, Experience, Education

I want to know:

How can I resister myself as a developer
How can I get the enough privilage to obtain the info above
How can I write / submit the script to do the procedure above

Do you have such experience?

It looks like it certainly is possible.
Go take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api. This has all the information that you request to fetch. On how to get access as developer I would look into their documentation - and if you run into more specific problems I would use stackOverflow. But this question is very broad and hard to give a precise answer on.
